# Asus Transformer Infinity Pad (TF700KL) how to cold boot (enter Recovery Mode)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, device-firmware, downgrade, asus-transformer-infinity

I have a TF700KL bought from Vodafone. I am unable to go into Recovery mode. I've found some links telling me how to do this, such as the one on the XDA-Developers site:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=30223822#post30223822

(look for the section titled "Factory Restore after a softbrick/Downgrade from Jelly Bean to ICS/Clean Factory Restore")

Here, as well as on many similar articles, it says to first "Enter recovery mode" by shutting down tablet, holding volume-down and power for 5 seconds, and when some message appears, press volume up.

Thing is, when I start my tablet up by holding volume-down and power I get the following:

- if the usb cable is not connected to the computer, I get a message like "No USB Cable connected" under a logo of a usb cable connector and a big question mark sign:

[image]

- if, at this point, I connect it to the computer via the USB cable, my Windows computer says it's installing some driver (which it succeeds in installing), and then the tablet goes on to display a "ready for download" message under a logo of an android guy wearing a yellow hard-hat (kindda looks like Kyle's brother from Southpark):

[image]

After this I can't do anything other than hold power button for a longtime to restart the tablet normally. I have no visible menu, option, etc. Also I've waiting here for like 10 minutes, nothing seems to actually get downloaded or get ready for anything.

In short, I never managed to get to the menus described in the tutorials I've found for this tablet. My hunch now is that I have the LTE version and most people have the non-LTE version and they behave differently on this.

So my question is:

- does anyone know how to go into recovery mode on this tablet,

or

- what's the deal with the menus I describe here (and show in the pictures)

or

- how to go to recovery mode, do a cold boot, do a manual Android upgrade/downgrade from these menus I get?

Comment: Does the tablet work otherwise (what does turning it on normally do)? Can you push commands to the tablet through adb or fastboot? Did you try other button combinations? What are the devices that the drivers install? I believe that the download mode allows for flashing bootloaders.

Comment: 1. No. Sometimes turning it on results in a full restart (as if it had been shut down prior to it, though it hasn't - very annoying) 2. Never tried, but it should work. Don't know how to cold boot it via adb tho... 3. Yes, starting it while holding volume up gives me a menu that allows for factory reset, SD card down mode. 4. It installs something like "ASUS Tablet Infinity bla bla" 5. Yes, I kindda think that too, but as I said, when displaying "Ready for download" there's nothing I can do to it other than restart it (atleast, nothing obvious).

Answer (score 2):

Once you get to the USB logo,  press the volume up and down together once and it should bring you into recovery.

Comment: Doesn't work for me